# Under what product names is Hydrogen Peroxide marketed in Israel?

Tags: names, israel

[Hydrogen Peroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide) is a chemical compound which has various household uses, mostly cleaning/disinfecting/bleaching. But - if you enter your local super-market or ("super-pharm"-like) stores and pass through the cleaning, laundry and toiletries aisles you'll not find that name featuring on any product. Even if you look for cleaning agents, it seems not to be part of the selection.

So is it not typically in use in Israel? Is it sold elsewhere/under another name?

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr: Look for "מי חמצן".

This compound - whose formula is H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> - has a specific Hebrew name; or rather, two such names. Unofficially and commonly, it's known as מי חמצן. Translated, that's "Oxygen Water", and transliterated: "Mei Hamtzan". The official chemical name is [מימן על-חמצני](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A0%D7%99) (Hebrew Wikipedia).

Pharmacies/"pharm" stores typically stock it, and super-markets might as well; a few examples of the packaging: [here](https://shop.super-pharm.co.il/pharmacy/external-treatment/external-use/%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A3-%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%9F-3%25-100-%D7%9E%D7%9C/p/236588), [here](http://floris.co.il/product/%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%9F-3/) and [here](https://www.bela.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%9F-%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%95%D7%97%D7%99%D7%98%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%A4%D7%A6%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D-3-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%95%D7%96). There's also some gel form of it, e.g. [here](https://www.shufersal.co.il/online/en/categories/SUPERMARKET/Hygiene-and-babies/Hair-Care/%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%A2-%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A8/%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%9D-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%9F-9%25-%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%9C/p/P_7296073242321). Note that the concentration of H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> is not the same in all products.